# Error when retrieving data from the Arduino serial port with the C programming language

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, readfile, arduino-uno

I want to retrieve data through the serial port from Arduino with the C programming language in realtime. The program at Arduino :

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  }
   int i=1;
   void loop() {
   Serial.println(i);
   delay(1000);
   i++;
 }
```

Programs in c language:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hComm;
    hComm=CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM3",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL );
    BOOL Status;
    DCB dcbSerialParams={0};

    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status=GetCommState(hComm,&dcbSerialParams);

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_9600;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;

    Status=SetCommState(hComm,&dcbSerialParams);

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant=50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier=10;

    Status=SetCommMask(hComm,EV_RXCHAR);

    DWORD dwEventMask;
    Status=WaitCommEvent(hComm,&dwEventMask,NULL);

    char TempChar;
    char SerialBuffer[256];
    DWORD NoBytesRead;
    int i=0;

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("data.txt", "w");
        do{
            Status=ReadFile(hComm,&TempChar,sizeof(TempChar),&NoBytesRead,NULL);
            SerialBuffer[i]=TempChar;
           printf("%c",SerialBuffer[i]);
           fprintf(fp, "%c", SerialBuffer[i]);
            i++;
         }
        while(1);

     CloseHandle(hComm);

    return 0;
}
```

When running, an error occurs:

[image]

Please help, what is the problem that caused the error? What is the correct program?

Comment: Please don't show images of text, copy-paste the text as text into the question instead.

Comment: As for your error that's a crash, it's an *access violation* error which you should have found very quickly if you just put `0xc0000005` into a search engine. To begin to understand what's going on you should use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens, which will tell you where in your code it happens and also let you examine the values of the involved variables at that point.

Comment: You need to check status of ReadFile and also if `NoBytesRead` is 1, before attempting to print the data. Otherwise you will end up printing non-printable characters or whatever, until you overrun the buffer of 256 bytes, after which your program is designed to crash.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments 0xc0000005 is an access violation.

Without putting much time into reading your code (you should debug it yourself) I'd say it in general is a bad idea to increment a variable within an infinite loop if that variable is used to index an array.

Also you never check of your ReadFile actually succeeds.

There is a reason why C books do not cover reading files befor indexing arrays and using control structures properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed the codes and the program running successly. Let me show you the codes:
<pre>

do{
           Status=ReadFile(hComm,&TempChar,sizeof(TempChar),&NoBytesRead,NULL);
           printf("%c",TempChar);
           fprintf(fp, "%c", TempChar);
            i++;
  }
 while(NoBytesRead > 0);

</pre>